# If coral didn't exist, would jellyfish not exist either? (Or vice versa)

Tags: evolution

Is the evolution of corals, sea anenomes and jellyfish intrinsically linked to the point where if say corals did not evolve, neither would jellyfish? Or vice versa.

Comment: Hello and welcome Jefferey. How did you come to the conclusion coral & Jelly fish are reliant on each other?

Comment: They both evolved around the same time and are part of the same phylum. Do they have a common ancestor? I'm not saying their reliant per say.

Comment: Poor wording on my behalf. But is seems although the relationship is not clear. https://www.britannica.com/animal/cnidarian/Evolution

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! I don't think I understand your question — can you clarify what it is that you are asking?. Are you thinking that different lineages within a group are somehow dependent after they've separated from each other? If so why? If not, then why would the extinction of corals (or their failure to ever form a separate lineage) have any effect on jellies? ——— As an analogy, does the failure of the hominid lineage to form trolls have any effect on humans or the other great apes? What does that question even mean?

Comment: I was a little tired when I wrote this. I think the answer provided understood what I was getting at, though even in hindsight I can barely grasp what 1AM me was getting at. Heh, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this article](https://bmcevolbiol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2148-13-5) with phylogenetic trees of Cnidaria answering your question.
You should note that phylogenetic tress are statistical models based on sequencing. They may change depending on the methods used, the organismed sampled and the genes used for comparison
I translated the groups you mentioned to the following biological names:
Corals - Hexocorallia and Octocorallia
Sea anenomes - Actinaria (Hexocorallia)
Jellyfish - Medusozoa
(Not the same levels)

Judging by [Figure 3](https://media.springernature.com/lw685/springer-static/image/art%3A10.1186%2F1471-2148-13-5/MediaObjects/12862_2012_Article_2274_Fig3_HTML.jpg) (don't know if I'm allowed to post the figure to this site)
And my limited knowledge in the subjet they each group could've evolve seperatley with a higher linkage between jellyfish & corals(octocorallia) than to sea anenomas.
Sea anenomas and corals(hexocorallia) are very closly linked and sea anenomas appear at the first junction of the tree which means that if sea anenomas did not exists neither the rest of the group.